# How to keep spaces at the end of AutoHotKey snippets?

Tags: autohotkey

How to keep spaces at the end of `AutoHotKey` snippets? No matter how many I place in my ahk file, no spaces are present on execution.

Comment: can you share an example?

Answer (score 3):

Add {space} at the end of the command,

e.g.

```
Send myName{space}
Send abc{space 2} ; add 2 spaces after abc
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your needs, but usually you can use the built-in variable %A_Space% for that.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can add an escape after your space like this:

```
:*: ive :: I've `
```

Comment: Escape seems to be a little complicated for me. I assume it must mask the neighboring symbol (I now mask with "{}")? This code 

`::s::`
`Send,`
`(`
`s+\`s`
`)`
`return`

gets this result:

`sS`